# Hanoi specific problem

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, towers-of-hanoi

Suppose that there are 2*n disks, How could be Hanoi problem solved if odd numbers are disks on bar "A" and even disks are on bar "B"?
please Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks

Comment: actually... what are we trying to do with the disks?  According to this discussion: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/127768-towers-hanoi-variation.html they are probably being swapped?

Comment: We are trying to move all disks on bar "C" while disks are separated into two parts "odds" and "evens". odds are on bar "A" and evens on "B". Suppose disk with number "1" is the biggest, "2" after "1" is the biggest and so on.

Comment: ok, so my interpretation was correct, your problem is different from the one I linked above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

move disk 1 onto disk 2
then move the resulting "proper" hanoi towner 1,2 onto disk 3 using the classic algorithm.
Then move the proper tower 1,2,3 onto 4.  Continue until you get the full proper tower, then use classic algorithm to move to the destination.

EDIT1:

Example (incomplete)

```
1   2
3   4
5   6   
.   .   .

    1
    2
3   4
5   6   
.   .   .

    1
    2
    4
5   6   3
.   .   .

    2
1   4   
5   6   3
.   .   .

1   4   2   
5   6   3
.   .   .

        1
    4   2   
5   6   3
.   .   .

        1
4       2   
5   6   3
.   .   .
```

This is curious because the last step is a little bit of an optimization; what I described would try to build 1-2-3-4-6 but we jump directly to building 1-2-3-4-5.  This probably means something.

Comment: Would you mind give an example with 6 disks?! 1,2,3 on "A" and 2,4,6 on "B". Classic algorithm is O(2^n), what about this algorithm?

Comment: @IVlad, @Hosi see my edit.  Complexity should still be 2^n (can't get worse than that)

Comment: @MK - do you have a recursive formulation? Your example seems to be different from what you described. What you described should perform `(2^2 - 1) + (2^3 - 1) + (2^4 - 1) + ... + (2^(2n) - 1)` steps. In your example however, you never move `1 2` on the destination peg and `1 2 3` onto `4` for example, which does reduce the number of steps, but I'm not sure how you'd formulate it recursively.

Comment: I mean in what order it is exactly. As you know, classic Hanoi is: T(n)=2T(n-1)+O(n) that leads to O(2^n). what about for this version of problem?!

Comment: @Hosi So I think you'll be moving 2^2 + 2^3 + ...+ 2^(n-1) + 2^n which still O(2^n) since is is just 2^(n+1) - 1

Comment: @IVlad you are right.  I tried to optimize and forgot about the algorithm :) will have to think about formalizing the optimization.